# Output is not shown in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
char DayName(int day_th)
{
  const char *DayName[] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday" };
  return *DayName[day_th];
}

int main()
{
  int day_th=2;
  printf("What is your favorite day of the week? 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday: \n");
  printf("Day %d is a %s", day_th, DayName(day_th-1));
  return 0;
}
```

I am writing a code that have output like "Day 2 is Monday". I am using VS 2019 and the compiler does not raise any errors. However, when I hit run, only "What is your favorite day ... line" is shown but not the "Day 2 is Monday". Pleases help! Many thanks.

Comment: End the output witha newline.

Comment: Do turn on compiler warnings and listen to it.

Answer (score 4):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by passing data having wrong type to *printf*: `char` is passed where `char*` is expected (`%s`).

The function `DayName` should return the elements of the array `const char*` without dereferencing them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char* DayName(int day_th)
{
  const char *DayName[] = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday" };
  return DayName[day_th];
}

int main()
{
  int day_th=2;
  printf("What is your favorite day of the week? 1 is Sunday and 7 is Saturday: \n");
  printf("Day %d is a %s", day_th, DayName(day_th-1));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I assumed it was the "didn't flush stdout due to missing `\n`" issue!